# Show/Hide content inside ul li

Tags: jquery, find, toggle

I want to show/hide content inside `li` by clicking on a link, just like the 'more information' button. The code I have hides the content of every `li`, not just the clicked one. Please take a look:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul li').on('click', '.abrir', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul li').find('.oculto').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    Biológica
    <span class="abrir">>></span>
    <span class="oculto">Texto oculto para mostrar</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    Oxidativa
    <span class="abrir">>></span>
    <span class="oculto">Texto oculto para mostrar</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    Pasificación
    <span class="abrir">>></span>
    <span class="oculto">Texto oculto para mostrar</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    Dulzor
    <span class="abrir">>></span>
    <span class="oculto">Texto oculto para mostrar</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're selecting all the `li` elements in the click handler, not the one which contained the `.abrir` element that triggered the event.

To do that, you can use the `this` keyword, as jQuery sets the scope of event handler functions to be the element which raised the event. From there you can use the `siblings()` method to retrieve the related `.oculto` element. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul li').on('click', '.abrir', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('.oculto').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.oculto { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    Biológica
    <span class="abrir">>></span>
    <span class="oculto">Texto oculto para mostrar</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    Oxidativa
    <span class="abrir">>></span>
    <span class="oculto">Texto oculto para mostrar</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    Pasificación
    <span class="abrir">>></span>
    <span class="oculto">Texto oculto para mostrar</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    Dulzor
    <span class="abrir">>></span>
    <span class="oculto">Texto oculto para mostrar</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of this `$('ul li').find('.oculto').toggle();` Just use this `$(this).parent().find('.oculto').toggle();`, in  your code you are hiding all the li elements not just clicked one.

Answer (score 1):

In your script, instead of using

`$('ul li').find('.oculto').toggle();`

please use

```
$(this).parent().find('.oculto').toggle();
```

and also add the below code snippets with your CSS code.

```
.oculto { display: none; }
.abrir {
   color: blue;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Example right below :

```
***Script***
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('ul li').on('click', '.abrir', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().find('.oculto').toggle();
            });
        });

***In CSS***

.oculto { display: none; }
    .abrir {
       color: blue;
       cursor: pointer;
    }
```